# How to add swagger in existing servlet project

Tags: servlets, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to add swagger to an existing servlet project and I have done my web.xml as shown

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DefaultServletConfig</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.swagger.servlet.config.DefaultServletConfig</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>swagger.resource.package</param-name>
      <param-value>bsnl.inbound</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
      <param-value>http://localhost:8080/comm</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>api.version</param-name>
      <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ApiDeclarationServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.swagger.servlet.listing.ApiDeclarationServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ApiDeclarationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

It is working for only one class in a package and only for the GET method, it is not calling the post method. But I want to configure for multiple packages.
If anyone having any idea, please help me.

Comment: Is the Swagger working only in /api/* classes?

Comment: If suppose I have multiple classes in bsnl.inbound package, I am getting only one class called from swagger and only doGet method, not doPost.Also, I want to add multiple packages to call from swagger.